# How to see errors in magento?

Tags: magento-1.7

Page says 'There has been an error processing your request

Exception is disabled by for security reasons.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a file name local.xml.sample in errors folder of you magento directory.

Rename it to local.xml and refresh the browser page showing error.